# Elasticsearch not returning result with same token?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, token

Data inserted in ElasticSearch is in korean so I cannot present exact case but let's say
i have a word `ABBCC` that has been tokenized as `["A","BBCC"]` and another word `AZZXXX`tokenized as `["A","ZZXXX"]`.

if i search ABBCC, then shouldn't AZZXXX come up since they have same token? or is this not how elasticsearch work?

this is how I checked analyzed words:

```
GET recpost_test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text":"my query String!" 
}
```

this is how i created my index:

```
PUT recpost
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "tokenizer": {
          "nori_user_dict": {
            "type": "nori_tokenizer",
            "decompound_mode": "mixed",
            "user_dictionary": "userdict_ko.txt"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "nori_user_dict"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is how i searched:

```
GET recpost/_search
{
  "_source": [""],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 2,
  "query":{
    "multi_match": {
      "query" : "my query String!",
      "type": "best_fields", 
      "fields" : [
        "brandkor",
        "content",
        "itemname",
        "name",
        "review",
        "shortreview^2",
        "title^3"]
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I tried adding "analyzer" field to search and still doesn't work

```
GET recpost/_search
{
  "_source": [""],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 2,
  "query":{
    "multi_match": {
      "query" : "깡스",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
      "type": "best_fields", 
      "fields" : [
        "brandkor",
        "content",
        "itemname",
        "name",
        "review",
        "shortreview^2",
        "title^3"]
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT2: This is my mapping:

```
{
  "recpost_test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "brandkor" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "field_statistics" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "itemname" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "offsets" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "payloads" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "positions" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "review" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "shortreview" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "term_statistics" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use your analyzer in the multi_match, don't you ?

Comment: @baitmbarek I tried setting the analyzer (added as EDIT) still doesn't work..

Comment: Try ‘tie_breaker: 1.0’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see that you mounted your fields to your index(mapping).
so for all I know, is that you're indexing all of the fields (brandkor, content, ...etc) as `text` .. and basically you're matching exact values.

unless you correlated each field with its analyzer.

Comment: I thought that if I set the analyzer when I created index, it would use that analyzer as default to analyze text fields. Is that not the case?

Comment: recreated index and mapped text field with my custom analyzer and it works now! thanks!